# detecting mouseClick/touch on gameObject

Tags: c#, events, input, unity-game-engine, unityscript

the system never detect my mouse/touch Click on a gameObject (the right or left arrow , check the below link)

```
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    //don`t enter here!!
    if (this.name == "gameObjectName")
       doAction();
}
```

[image]

Comment: which value does this.name have?

Comment: @duffy356 "Left Arrow-50" , as you can see in the image

Comment: Uh, what language is the being written in? I had assumed it was Java because of the `public void` method declaration, but I don't see a Unity binding for Java.

Comment: What does the rest of your class structure look like? Please post more code.

Comment: James , I edited the question , check the update please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your script is attached to the *Left Arrow-50* game object, first of all make sure both of them have *collider* components.

After that, rewrite your code removing the **if** line. Only the instance of your script that is attached to the clicked object will be called, so you don't need this line to check if this is the right object.

```
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    doAction();
}
```

Do the same with the *Right Arrow-50* and its script.

Comment: I did not expect that the problem that I'm looking for its solution several days ago
caused by not putting a collider component

Answer (score 0):

Since your instance variable name has the value "Left Arrow-50" the condition is false and your doAction-Mehtod does not get called.

It's difficult to help you, since we don't know what gameObjectName is. Is it a variable or a String?

if its a String variable, try the following code:

```
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (this.name.equals(gameObjectName)) // - if gameObjectName is a variable, containing the name of game object
       doAction();//never enter here!!
}
```

Comment: guys , it is not enter the whole function at all

Comment: still looking for a solution -_-

Comment: print (gameObject.transform.name); This prints the current GameObject Name